# (React)Filter through api by search term

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, search

I'm trying to use a search bar component in my React project to search/filter through an api list of movies by title. Right now my search term is console logging, but i'm trying to filter the movie list to only show the titles that match the term. I'm having issues with updating my movies state with the term and displaying the new array.

App

```
import SearchBar from "../Search/SearchBar"

export default function Movies() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  async function getMovies() {
    const movieData = await fetchMovies();

    console.log(movieData);
    setMovies(
      movieData.data.data.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title))
    );
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, []);

 async function onSearchSubmit(term) {
    console.log(term)
    let fill = []
    movies.filter((movie) => {
        if(movie.title === term) {
           fill.push(movie.title)
        }
       setMovies(fill)

    })
    }

  return (
    <>
      <Nav 
      movies={movies}
      setMovies={setMovies}/>
      <SearchBar
      onSubmit={onSearchSubmit}/>

      {movies ? (
        <div>
          <div>
            {movies.map((m, idx) => {
              return <div key={idx}>{m.title}</div>;
            })}{" "}
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        "loading..."
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Search Bar component

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

const SearchBar = ({onSubmit}) => {

    const [term, setTerm] = useState("")


    function onFormSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        onSubmit(term)
        
        }

    return ( 
        
        <div className="ui segment">
        <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
          <div className="field">
            <label>Movie Search</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={term}
              onChange={(e) => setTerm( e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
     );
}
 
export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all additional state is needed to record the loaded moves list:

```
const movies = useRef([]);
const [filteredMovies, setFilteredMovies] = useState([]);
```

It is better to declare handlers with `useCallback` and avoid the mixture of declarative and imperative styles. For example:

```
const onSearchSubmit = useCallback(async (term) => {
  if (term) {
    const _ = movies.current.filter(({ title }) => (title === term));
    setFilteredMovies(_);
  } else {
    setFilteredMovies(movies.current);
  }
}, [movies]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pq9xkewz/2/

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked! I def need to study useRef and UseCallback :)

Comment: One last question, If I had another options select form and I wanted to filter by genre, it would be the same structure? or would I need to set a third state?

Comment: and genres for each movie is an array

Comment: Yep, In most cases, it is better to declare useState for each singular field.

But if you are going to introduce a bunch of fields (some kind of search form) it is better to utilize some form-management library. For example, https://formik.org/docs/overview

Comment: i keep getting "includes is not defined" am I doing this right?

Comment: ` const onGenreSubmit = useCallback(
    async (genre) => {
      console.log(genre);
      if (genre) {
        const g = movies.current.genres.includes((genre));
        console.log(g);
        setFilteredMovies(g);
      } else {
        setFilteredMovies(movies.current);
      }
    },
    [movies]
  );`